Saving PDF from Third Party App Causes Permission Issue - Android Kotlin
I have an app which copies .pdf files from assets and saves them locally. The user can then open the .pdf in a third party app using intents to make annotations and then save the .pdf. Once the user saves the annotated .pdf, I now lose permission to the .pdf. For instance, if they save it in the same location (overwriting original file), I receive EACCES PERMISSION DENIED when trying to reopen it. If the user saves it in a separate directory, I don't receive an error but it's as if the file doesn't exist. When I check to see if the directory exists with .exists(), it returns true but when I run listFiles() on the directory, it returns null.
Below is an example of the directory I am using.
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/Folder Name")
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/Folder Name").exists()
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/Folder Name").listFiles()

My understanding is I don't need to request permissions but for the heck of it, I did add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> to my manifest and this did not solve the issue. Any ideas why this is happening?

You only have access to files in Documents/ that were created by your app. A typical approach to saving changes to a file, particularly one like a PDF, is to write out a new file under a temporary name, delete the original file, then rename the new file to the original file's name. A side effect of this technique is that your app loses rights to access the file, because you created the now-deleted original copy, not the modified one.
Please use the Storage Access Framework:

ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT / ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument to open existing PDFs
ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT / ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument to create new PDFs

This not only lets you get past the permission issues, but it gives the user freedom to store the PDFs where they want, rather than your hard-coded location.

thanks, this is interesting. Is there a way to invoke the Scope Storage Access Framework without taking user input and without displaying the UI? I'm trying to merge two PDFs. The first PDF is programmatically created within my app. The second is the annotated PDF, which although originally stored in app assets and copied to local storage, is being created by third party app (adobe, samsung notes, etc.).

@Whitt: "Is there a way to invoke the Scope Storage Access Framework without taking user input and without displaying the UI?" -- no. The point behind the SAF is to involve the user in the decision-making regarding where content gets stored and accessed. "copied to local storage" -- have you tried storing in getContext().getExternalFilesDir() and using FileProvider to provide a Uri to the third-party app?

@CommonWare: Yes, that is how the "copied" pdf is being provided to the third party apps.
`val fileName = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS  + "/" + Folder Name + "/" + File Name)
val file = FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(), "com.authority", fileName)
    if(fileName.exists()) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
            setFlags(....)`


@Whitt: "Yes, that is how the "copied" pdf is being provided to the third party apps" -- the code in that comment is using Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(), which is not what I am suggesting. I am suggesting using getContext().getExternalFilesDir(), which is a location fully under your control, requiring no permissions, and not suffering the limitations of Documents/.

@CommonWare: Aha, I see what you're suggesting now, sorry for misunderstanding. I will test this out and report back. Thanks.

@CommonWare: When I save the document via the third party app, I don't know how to save it in the getExternalFilesDir() without including Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS or DOWNLOADS; is that possible?

@Whitt: I am going to guess that you mean that you are opening the third party app using the ACTION_VIEW code from a few comments ago, and then when you go to save changes, it prompts you for a location to save to. If the third party app does not let you just save where it opened the PDF from, either you missed the write flag in setFlags(), or the app just assumes that it can't write there. You won't have a way in the third party app UI to put the content back into getExternalFilesDir(), as the third party app does not have filesystem access to that locaiton.

You were correct in your assumption.               Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION                             or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION                             or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP                             or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT                             or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
Thanks for taking the time to help out. I feel like I've exhausted my knowledge at this point. It must be that the app is assuming it can't write to getExternalFilesDir(). It seems it's not possible to save in a third party app and then...

get access to merge in my app.
